# How to use Genymotion to launch an android app on PC?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I created an android project with the eclipse ADT from the android-bundle, and generated the apk. I downloaded and installed Genymotion with the integrated Oracle Virtualbox on my computer running Windows XP. How to run my application with Genymotion ?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a genymotion emulator running ADB will detect it and give you the option to install it directly on it from eclipse. Another option is to install it through terminal by doing:

```
adb install myapk.apk
```

Before using adb from terminal remember to set up ANDROID_HOME, and add ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools to the path. Hope this helps

Comment: What is adb in fact ?

Comment: Its a command line tool you get with the development kit for android. More info here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: What should be the value to set for ANDROID_HOME ?

Comment: ANDROID_HOME should be set to the sdk folder.

Comment: For example : `D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk` ?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the answer with a correction, you have to add platform-tools to the path to get adb from command line.

Comment: How does adb know which apk to install when writing `adb install myapk.apk` ?

Comment: replace the "myapk.apk" with the actual filename you want to install

Comment: Even if there are many android projects then adb will find the right apk ?

Comment: You will have to either run the command with a relative or absolute path to the file, or from the folder where the apk is located

Answer (score 3):

if you have APK than just Drag and Drop to Genymotion emulator by default it store in
 `/sdcard/download`(its **toast** location where store file) go to there and manually install your APK 
 you can also put any file not only APK :)

This is online plugin for eclipse `http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse`

after install it you can use as native emulator.You can find icon in eclipse menu start emulator from it and run project

Comment: After that how to launch the app ? Which button to click ?

Answer (score 1):

To deploy an application to a virtual device, use either of the following methods:

> Drag and drop the application APK file into the virtual device window.
> Run the following command: adb install .apk.
> Download and install the application directly from the virtual device
> using a web link.